# Using Python 2.7 modules in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

I have implemented a Stack.py module that I would like to be able to import, but when I tried to save it to usr/lib/python2.7 Ubuntu didn't allow it.
Now, I go to usr/lib and python2.7 folder doesn't even show up anymore in the graphic interface, although I am able to see it is still there by using sudo.

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did it show up before?

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: A better option would be to add it to your PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

How did you write the original Stack.py? If you used a text editor (without elevating it to super user) you'll have to save it somewhere you have write permissions (Desktop, for example) and then you could do:

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/Stack.py /usr/lib/python2.7
```

That being said, I think this is more a question for the AskUbuntu site (also a part of Stack Exchange).

If that doesn't work you could simply put Stack.py in the directory with the file you want to use it with and do

```
from Stack import [what you want to import/use]
```

or

```
from Stack import *
```